# Wrap Image on cylindrical image using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, word-wrap, cylindrical

I want to wrap one image on another image (This image will be containing object like cylinder.)
This will be the same effect like wrapper on any bottle.
I want to achieve it in asp.net.

I tried to search over internet but could not find the solution.
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: you want to have some kind of Texture mapping? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping

Comment: Not texture mapping but want to have effect like there is one image of one cylinder and there is another image which will gets wrapped on that cylinder image.

Comment: maybe I'm old fashioned and don't know some fancy library which you can  achive this. But for my understanding you need a 3D Model of your Cylinder or even more complex object. Than you can apply a Image to this Model. Than you render a new Image. At least for me it's quite unclear how you want to achive this with pure bitmaps as you don't have any geometrical reference points.

Comment: @SagarJoshi did you find anything useful? I have same requirement with bottles.